# JQuery mouse pointer flickers on hover

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, mouseevent

i am trying to make a  mega menu using bootstrap 4 , i found this code :

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tryit.php/vHkK2j9nFZ

it works just fine  but i want the drop-down content to be revealed when the mouse hovers on the dropdown link white a SlideDown/SlideUp effect  so i added this jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown").hover(            
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown("400");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');        
    },
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');       
    }
  );
});
```

the slidedown/slideup effect work fine but when the mouse pointer is inside the dropdown-content it starts  to flicker

can anyone tell me how to fixe this problem
thank you

Comment: That is a common event timing effect. When mouse is out, event occurs... When it is in, another event occurs. When you are on the line... Many instances of those event fires. -- Look for `debouncing` keyword.

Comment: No one can tell more specific solution with the small code snippet you provide..

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks you for your  response and i found the solution actually there was a  space (padding) between the drop-down link and the drop-down content and when  the mouse enter that area it starts to flicker so i deleted the padding

Comment: Good! You can answer your own question. Ideally, make a code snippet which reproduce the issue and explain the solution you found. It may be useful for future readers. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i just did it :)

Answer (score 1):

as @LouysPatriceBessette requested  [this is the full code en codepen](https://codepen.io/NAS_95/pen/xxGEmbR) showing the issue .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").hover(
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("400");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    },
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("400");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<div class="fluid-container">
  <center>

    <b>Bootstrap 4 full width dropdown in Navbar</b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark 
      justify-content-between text-white" style="background-color: blue;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/gfg_transparent_white_small.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> GfG BS4 Navbar
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown01" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="outline-color:#fff"> 
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
    </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown01">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ">

          <!--dropdown item of menu-->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
       Dropdown 01 
       </a>

            <!--dropdown sub items of menu-->
            <div class="dropdown-menu mt-0 w-100 
          shadow border-outline-success" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 
        Another action 
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> 
         Something else here 
        </a>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>

        <!--Form item of menu for search purpose-->

      </div>
    </nav>
  </center>
</div>
```

For the solution, you just grab this line of code (line 28) :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark justify-content-between text-white" 
     style="background-color: blue;">
```

and inside the class attribute you just add `p-0` it means you are removing all padding  the result will be :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark justify-content-between text-white p-0" 
     style="background-color: blue;">
```

the navbar height is not smaller  to fix that you just add margins to each drop-down link 
(line 56):
without margins:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
```

with margins:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle m-2"
```

Comment: I added a code snippet to make sure the code about the problem reproduction won't be lost. ;)